# Sort Fullcalendar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a problem with my Fullcalendar ( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ ) events output. Now I can get a full output of all events, but I want to make some change to it so it can display the events in an order that defined in a array. 
For example, I want the events to be sorted by title following the order {"Jack", "Tom", "Ben"}.

But sometimes there may only be Jack and Ben's events so I would like my display still follow the array order but skip the ones that are missing. 

I searched around and the only way I can find is to make some change to the fullcalendar.js `function segCmp(a, b)` .

 I am just asking if there is any other solution for this issue, or this is the only way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: Events on a calendar are generally sorted by date... Do you mean that you wish to sort events which occur on the same day?

Comment: @JAAulde Yes I want all the events in a day are sorted by the order I defined. Is there any possible way to do it? Just want to make sure I can control the order of the events.

Comment: I don't believe any edits to the plugin will be necessary. Fullcalendar offers many ways to provide it data, and many hook points to manipulate that data. To offer you the best advice for your situation, we would need to see the code you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would indeed need to change segCmp(a, b).  That shouldn't be too bad though, the sliceSegs function below it tells you what the parameters are you need to work with to generate the sort order you're after. a.event.title and b.event.title will give you the titles of the segments.